# Cannot add clip from samba share

Tags: samba, kdenlive

I'm using kdenlive on mate-desktop, and I cannot add clip from samba share.

Out of the app I can't access these file with no problems.

Any ideas?

[image: Dialog Box]

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the issue mounting by hand instead of rely on dbus/gvfs whitchcraft, and then I could add the clips